Grafana : How to add vertical line/background color for the first and last specified duration in window
I am monitoring some metrics in Grafana v10.3.3 from an InfluxDB v2.7.4 datasource. I have a Time Series panel with a moving average query from InfluxDB. (The MA calculation is done by the Flux query so the data Grafana gets is already the data I want to show.)
The problem is that the moving average is calculated over the last 10 minutes, so the first 10 minutes of moving average are calculated over less than 10 minutes of data, same for the last 10 minutes of moving average wcich are calculated based on less than 10 minutes of data, see screenshot :

This is very misleading when viewing the panel, mostly when the window range is about an hour or less.
So my question : How to make the first 10 minutes and the last 10 minutes of the window range appear in a different background color (kind of a threshold but for the x-axis) ? (To know which data is accurate and which is misleading)
Alternatively: How can I query data in range [start; end] and only show the data in range [start+10m; end-10m] in the panel to avoid that mislead ? (This would also solve the problem)
What I tried :
I tried to find a way to display a vertical line / a background color just like a threshold would but for the time axis (x-axis). I couldn't find such a functionnality in Grafana.
I also tried to find a Grafana transformation to select only a sub-range of the query range to show, which I couldn't find.
Question 60528255 does not answer my question : In that question the line is needed to be placed at specific timing, whereas my line/colored region needs to be at specific duration for each window range.
